Pulling element from the list
So I'm having a trouble. I'm working with python and I have a list that look like this example
['1', 'A', 'B', 'C', '1', 'D', '1', 'E', 'F', '1', 'G', 'H', 'I']

What I wanted is to make a list out of the elements between '1'
Like this
[['A', 'B', 'C'],['D'],['E', 'F'],['G', 'H', 'I']]

Anyone can give me an advice on how to achieve this?

what trouble are you having, precisely? How does your current code not do what you want?

The resulting list list is inconsistent. Shouldn't it start with an empty list? Because the first element of your input list is a '1' that you use to split the list, so for consistency your resulting list should be [[],['A', 'B', 'C'],['D'],['E', 'F'],['G', 'H', 'I']]. If that's not the case then you should explain the logic behind what you want. You say "list out of the elements between '1'" but then the last 3 elements 'G', 'H', 'I' are not "between" "1", so they should be discarted?

What if there are two consecutive '1' elements?

Duplicate? How to split a list-of-strings into sublists-of-strings by a specific string element

What have you tried so far? You should have at least one attempt or at least an idea of how you might accomplish this. SO is not the best place to ask for people to do things for you without showing you have put in some kind of effort first.

One method would be to use itertools.groupby() to split the list into consecutive groups based on whether they are equal to '1'. As the docs note:

The key is a function computing a key value for each element.

If we set it to lambda x: x != '1' then we can get the desired output by only including groups where key==True.
import itertools

l = ['1', 'A', 'B', 'C', '1', 'D', '1', 'E', 'F', '1', 'G', 'H', 'I']

def split_list(l: list[str], split_by: str):
    return [
        list(group) for key, group in 
        itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: x != split_by) if key
    ]

split_list(l, '1')
# [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]


You can test this ( for me it works ) :
def split_list(lst):
    result = []
    sublist = []
    for item in lst:
        if item == '1':
            if sublist:  # append the sublist to result if not empty
                result.append(sublist)
                sublist = []  # reset sublist
        else:
            sublist.append(item)
    if sublist:  # append the last sublist
        result.append(sublist)
    return result

# Example usage:
original_list = ['1', 'A', 'B', 'C', '1', 'D', '1', 'E', 'F', '1', 'G', 'H', 'I']
result_list = split_list(original_list)
print(result_list)  # Output: [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]

